# Is there a way to recreate the shift system from Minecraft in unity using c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to know how to recreate the shift system. What I want to know is this (Shifting makes you go to the end of a cube/block, you move slower. Just that in general.

Answer (score 1):

**Change speed:** Detect that the shift key is pressed, if pressed change the value of your speed variable, i would use a multiplier:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("LeftShift"))
     sneak = 0.5f;
else 
     sneak = 1.0f;
speed = baseSpeed * sneak;
```

**Detect edge:** Use a downward raycast from your player when shift is pressed. (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html). Set maxDistance to be rather short, if you have ground under your feet it will return true, you do nothing. If there is nothing near under your feet, it will return false. The tricky thing here is that you can't just set the speed of your character to 0 because you would be permablocked. To solve this you will probably need multiple raycasts and make them work together to detect the orientation of the edge and only cancel out the movement direction that would make you fall of the edge. I'm not sure about the best way to do this but you will most likely need raycasts so check them out.

You might be interested in these tutorials:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h66IN1Pndd0&list=PLVsTSlfj0qsWEJ-5eMtXsYp03Y9yF1dEn